# DLL causes program to crash only when memory is allocated

Tags: c++, memory-management, dll, malloc, code-injection

I am writing a small DLL, which once injected into my target process, will find a `hwnd` and write the window's text to a file. I have it setup like this:

```
hWnd = FindWindow(L"tSkMainForm",NULL);
chat = FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, L"TConversationForm", NULL);
ofstream myfile("X:\\Handles.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    int len;
    len = SendMessage(chat, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0) + 1; // + 1 is for the null term.
    char* buffer = new char[len];
    SendMessageW(chat, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)len, (LPARAM)buffer);
    myfile.write(buffer,len); /* << buffer <<endl; */
    myfile.close();
    delete[] buffer;
}
```

It works for a seemingly random amount of time, then the application (Skype) crashes. It only crashes when I allocate memory. I have tried using `malloc` with:

```
char* buffer = (char*)malloc(len); //I even tried removing "(char*) before malloc
//Do the rest of the stuff here
free((void*) buffer);
```

But that crashes too.

My DLL calls `CreateThread`, adds an extra menu item via `AppendMenu`, and handles the messages for it, all perfectly. It just seems that allocating memory doesn't want to work, but only at random times. I am not sure, but I think Skype is overwriting my memory, or I am overwriting Skype's memory (how would I ensure that the two don't overwrite each other then?)

Also, I know an API exists for Skype, but I want to do it this way. I would use the Skype API if I wanted to write a serious program.
Thanks.

Comment: I am unsure, but a possible cause could be that `SendMessageW` is writing wide characters to `buffer` but `buffer` is a `char` buffer. Meaning its entire size is 50% less that what is required. Change the type of `buffer` to `wchar_t` and use `wofstream` instead.

Comment: @hmjd So far it has not crashed. Thank you.

Comment: I strongly recommend finding some documentation confirming this behaviour, and not relying on confirmation through observation. However, are you aware of `GetWindowText()` and `InternalGetWindowText()` ?

Comment: @hmjd Yes, I was using GetWindowText at once, but it crashed almost instantly once called, so I stuck to the older, semi-working SendMessageW. I'll probably switch to it once I am sure this is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it crashes. "Injecting a DLL in another process" is something you shouldn't be doing in the first place, and **certainly** not if you cannot figure this out.

Your problem is that your DLL makes assumptions about the environment it's running in. In particular, you assume there's a C++ heap (or a C heap, for `malloc`), and that is has precisely the right state for your program. That's just not the case. Normal C++ rules do not apply to injected DLL's; your DLL must be able to stand on its own legs.